# The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services, sha256

My test request for Amazon Web Service API is returning with the following error:

```xml
<ItemSearchErrorResponse xmlns="http://ecs.amazonaws.com/doc/2005-10-05/">
  <Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>
     The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
    </Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>ebe90459-1abd-403e-bfec-6916ebe07e1f</RequestId>
</ItemSearchErrorResponse>
```

Here is how I arrived at this:

```php
<?php

$private_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$date = urlencode(date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.Z\Z', time()));
$string_to_sign = "GET webservices.amazon.com /onca/xml/ AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXA&Keywords=Rocket&Operation=ItemSearch&SearchIndex=Toys&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=".$date."";
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256",$string_to_sign, $private_key, True)));
$url = "http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&Keywords=Rocket&Operation=ItemSearch&SearchIndex=Toys&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=".$date."&Signature=".$signature."";

header("Location: ".$url."");

?>
```

I basically wanted a signed REST request directly in the url (hence the header function) but left me stuck with the error. I double checked my access id and secret key so I know they are not the one causing the problem. Is this not the right way to produce the signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to use a V2 signature to call the REST API of AWS.
Please refer to the complete [AWS REST API call documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html).

My bet is the problem is the absence of `SignatureVersion`, `SignatureMethod` and `Version` in the string before signing. Step five of the documentation linked above shows and example of the string to be signed:

```
GET\n
elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com\n
/\n
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE&Action=DescribeJobFlows&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2011-10-03T15%3A19%3A30&Version=2009-03-31
```

Comment: Yes. I fixed it, but only doing \n and removing all blank spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This is AWS talk for: "Your credentials are incorrect".